# Help with stack-overflow error?

Tags: java, stack-overflow

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at apple.awt.CGraphicsDevice.getScreenInsets(Native Method)
    at apple.awt.CGraphicsDevice.getScreenInsets(CGraphicsDevice.java:673)
    at apple.awt.CToolkit.getScreenInsets(CToolkit.java:741)
    at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:394)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:432)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:403)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:368)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:158)
    at D3D.<init>(D3D.java:35)
    at player.<init>(player.java:1)
    at D3D.<init>(D3D.java:17)
    at player.<init>(player.java:1)
```

And here's the player class:

```
public class player extends D3D
{
  int playerX, playerY;
  boolean east, west, south, north;
  public void setPlayer()
  {
    playerX = 1; playerY = 1;
    east=true; west=false; north=false; south=false;
  }
}
```

And here's the D3D class:

```
public class D3D extends JFrame
{
  player player = new player();
  mapgeneration levelmap = new mapgeneration();
  boolean ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE;
  boolean ONEhighlight,TWOhighlight,THREEhighlight,FOURhighlight,FIVEhighlight;
  Timer timer = new Timer(250,new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      repaint();
    }
  });

  String tracer;

  Image Example = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("images/example.png");
  Image Startup = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("images/Startup.png");
  Image ButtonHighlight = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("images/ButtonHighlight.png");

  public D3D()
  {
    super();
    setSize(342,277);

      ...
    JPanel main = new JPanel()
    {
      public void paintComponent(final Graphics g)
      {
        super.paintComponent(g); 
        timer.start();
        g.drawImage(Startup,0,0,this);
        ...
      };
    };
    add(main);
  }
  public void init()
  {
    player.setPlayer();
    levelmap.populateGraph();
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    D3D game = new D3D();
    game.setTitle("Dungens:3D");
    game.init();
    game.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

I've been looking at this for hours and have narrowed it down to what you see here. To be honest, it's probably some stupid little petty thing that I'm glancing over.

Thanks guys.

Comment: I don't see where your recursion is unless it's because you're starting a Timer object in the paintComponent method (which is more than a little strange) and calling repaint() within this same Timer!  I think that you're going to need to create and post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for anyone to be able to solve this for you.

Comment: No, the Timer is declared outside the paintComp method; it's in the class. Maybe I can get it if someone can tell me what this means:   `at D3D.<init>(D3D.java:35)
 at player.<init>(player.java:1` Does that mean the error is occurring at line 35 of D3d and line 1 of player?

Comment: It's not causing recursion, but you're still running it in paintComponent, and to be frank you should simply not be doing that. No program logic should be called from that method.

Answer (score 5):

I see your problem. Your Player class extends your D3D GUI --  causing a kind of crazy circular referencing.  This will cause a recursion as you cyclically keep creating players and D3D objects.

To prove that I'm right, just run this very simple version of your code:

```
public class D3D {
   Player player = new Player();

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      D3D game = new D3D();
   }
}

class Player extends D3D {

}
```

So when the D3D object is created, it creates a Player object, and since it extends D3D, it creates another Player object which in turn since it's a D3D object, creates another Player object, and on and on.

But even if it didn't cause recursion, Player should never extend the GUI since a player is not a gui; they're totally different logical constructs.

Comment: Wait what. You're even **allowed** to do that? (ie no compiler error?) Good catch xX

Comment: @Voo: C/C++ isn't the only language that lets you shoot yourself in the foot (although C/C++ loads the gun and aims it for you).